# IF statement within PRINT not applying condition on full clause

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to print a chess like board with row and columns of size 'n'. Here's the working code

```
board = lambda x: [print(i[j],end=" " if j!=(n-1) else '\n') for i in x for j in range(len(i)) ]
```

To me, ideally the code should have been:

```
board = lambda x: [print(i[j],end=" " if j!=(n-1) else i[j]+'\n') for i in x for j in range(len(i)) ]
```

If condition seems to be working on `end` only and not on `i[j],end=" "`. Else is printing `i[j]` anyways

Answer (score 0):

It's because `i[j]` and `end=" "` are two independent statements.

For example, you can do something like this:

```
print(i[j] if False else 'H',end=" " if j!=(n-1) else i[j]+'\n'
```